# JSON Serialization crashing in swift

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization

I had been using the following line of code to parse JSON data in Objective-C, but the same in Swift crashes the app.

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:_webData
                          options:kNilOptions
                          error:&error];
```

I tried using `NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers` but doesn't seem to work. I have verified the validity of the JSON data obtained from the web server using various JSON validity checkers found online.

[EDIT] The swift code I am using is as follows:

```
let jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers , error: &error) as NSDictionary
```

[UPDATE]

Using `let jsonResult: AnyObject! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: error) as? NSDictionary` solves the issue.

Comment: You can't use `nil` with NS_OPTIONS-style enumerations - `NSJSONReadingOptions.fromMask(0)` will give you a "none of the above" value for that options type.

Comment: Remember that the return type of `+JSONObjectWithData:...` is `id`, not `NSDictionary*`. That method can return a `NSArray*`, for example, or `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error Xcode is giving you isn't very helpful, but it looks like you need to declare your `error` variable a different way ([more at Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13)), and then make sure you handle the case of the dictionary coming back `nil`:

```
var error: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSError?> = nil
let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
        options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers,
        error: error) as? NSDictionary
if jsonResult {
    // process jsonResult
} else {
    // couldn't load JSON, look at error
}
```

Comment: Nope. Still the same.

Comment: Can you double-check? That code made the difference for me. You're declaring `error` as a pointer this way, so you don't need to pass it by reference (i.e., `error: error` instead of `error: &error`).

Comment: I just did. Its still the same. And something weird I noticed about this issue is that it has issues only with certain JSON Inputs

Comment: Sorry - I was getting compiler errors with your original code, so I was trying to address that. I've updated with how you should handle the case where the JSON serialization fails.

Comment: Placing the code in `if` prevents the app from crashing. I am getting an error `VSs26AutoreleasingUnsafePointer (has 1 child)` in the error variable

Comment: Perfect! Now you just need to figure out why those JSON serializations are failing. Any other information in the error?

Comment: The crash was happening because you were trying to access the value of an implicitly unwrapped Optional (the return value from `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData()`) when that value was `nil`. That method should probably return `AnyObject?` instead of `AnyObject!` to make it clearer that you have to account for that case.

Comment: We've solved the issue you posted (crashing app with some JSON inputs), I think you'd need to post the failing JSON code to tackle the next issue.

Comment: The JSON code is quite long. How do I upload it here? Also since we are using an Error pointer instead of error variable, how do I access message stored in error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55521/discussion-between-nate-cook-and-jeswin).

Comment: I’m having the exact same issue and struggling to solve it. In my case I’m getting the data some times successfully and sometimes it fails. Using Swift 2.o

Answer (score 3):

All answers didn't work for me. This worked (21.01.2015 - Xcode 6.1.1 / iOS 8.1.2):

```
 var err: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil

 var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error:err) as NSDictionary
```

Found it here: [Use of undeclared type AutoreleasingUnsafePointer Xcode 6 beta 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699567/use-of-undeclared-type-autoreleasingunsafepointer-xcode-6-beta-6)

Answer (score 1):

Nil have to work, i think your error come from another problem, please post more code / crash log

```
    var err: NSError
    var jsonResult: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options:    NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
```

Can you try ?

Comment: _I had been using the following line of code to parse JSON data in Objective-C_

Comment: Using 0 gives this error `Cannot convert the expression's type 'NSDictionary' to type 'NSJSONReadingOptions'`

Comment: Can you post your swift code please ? I just read the doc and nil have to work. Did you have the "as NSDictionary" at the end ?

Comment: Your code is good maybe the crash don't come from your json options, what the crash is saying ?

Comment: It shows me the threads with `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT,sub code=0x0"`

Comment: `NSJSONSerialization` returns an Array of dictionaries in my case. Objective-C allows to type cast it to either an Array or Dictionary but swift allows only Arrays. It can be fixed by using `AnyObject` instead of `NSDictionary` checking if it is an array or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Created a NSDictionary to hold the data
var tempLocations : NSArray = NSArray()
var modelLocation : [Location] = [] // Will hold all the locations read in from datafile
// setup the path for the data
let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: fullPathForDataFile)

if let realJsonData = jsonData { // doing a test to check that the data exists
    tempLocations = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(realJsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSArray
    println("imported location data file with \(error) errors")
} else {
    // The data file does not exist, tell the user!
}

// For each set of object data in the json file do a loop.
for room in 1..<tempLocations.count {
    var newlocation : Location // This object contains var code:String?
    newlocation.code = tempLocations[room].valueForKey("code") as String
    // save the new location somewhere.
    modelLocation.addObject(newLocation)
}
```