# Use of undeclared type AutoreleasingUnsafePointer Xcode 6 beta 6

Tags: swift, xcode6

The following code gives a compiler error "Use of undeclared type AutoreleasingUnsafePointer"

```
    var myString: AutoreleasingUnsafePointer<NSString?>
```

Have I missed a compiler setup step?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

As stated in the [documentation revision history](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/RevisionHistory.html)

> Updated the Pointers section to reflect that `UnsafePointer` has been replaced with `UnsafeMutablePointer`, `ConstUnsafePointer` has been replaced with `UnsafePointer`, and `AutoreleasingUnsafePointer` has been replaced with `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer`.

So you have to use `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but, using NSError. In new version of Xcode (6.4) and Swift (previous version 2) it's necessary to use:

```
var err: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSError?> = nil
```